What do the different node colors mean in the Cytoscape ReactomeFIViz functional interaction network?
I'm a bit stuck trying to figure out how Cytoscape ReactomeFIViz decides how nodes are colored in my Cytoscape functional interaction network generated from my input RNAseq dataset (table).
Can you please clarify?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you show us an image of what you are seeing, perhaps? That could help. Have you looked at any of the tool's documentation?

Thank you terdon! I am unable to find the share/upload image option. However, what I am seeing looks something like the image under the 'Cluster FI network' paragraph on reactome.org/tools/reactome-fiviz#Gene_Set.2FMutation_Analysis . I looked through this documentation & under 4.1 Gene Set/Mutation Analysis
it says
Cluster FI network: run a network clustering algorithm (spectral partition based network clustering by Newman 2006) on the displayed FI network. Nodes in different network modules

will be shown in different colors (different colors used only for first 15 modules based on sizes).
What does this mean exactly?
Does the same apply to my analysis which uses
4.3 Microarray Data Analysis (even though the data I am analyzing is RNAseq)
?

I believe the clustering is based on connectivity, not your fold change values, so it would matter exactly how you got your network.
